# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

Tags: ios, macos

i am completely new to Mac OS and develop for iOS.
I created a TEST Unity3d Project using this tutorial:
https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing

Now i try to build the app in Xcode 8.2.1, but i just get an error:
["Unity-iPhone" isn't code signed but requires entitlements. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2' - screenshot 1]

I found many informations about this in the internet. But nothing worked for me.
The most informations in internet are for older xcode versions and i think apple changed many about code signing in xcode 8..

In Xcode Preferences, i use a default free AppleID with a default team.
[screenshot 2]

Trying to disable code signing did not work:
[screenshot 3]

Completely disable code signing also does not work:
[screenshot 4]

I use Mac OS El Capitan.
iPhone 7 v10.2.1

Can anyone help me out?

[All screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eICEg.png)

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. I don't know why people marked it down. I wish people would give a reason when they do that. Anyway, I had the same thing happen on a project I have been developing for a long time. I ran the simulator regardless of the error and it built and ran OK. I think perhaps it got stuck on some different target after running on a test device.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: In Xcode, click on the project at the top of the left column, then choose the target you're trying to build. Select the general tab, and check "Automatically manage signing."  You should also be able to run it in the simulator without even doing the above.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your great reply.
I had problems to find the "general" tab.

Then i found a great [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4SlR.gif) in another post to find the general tab.
With this screenhot and your great answer i got it working!

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get it working? If you got it working then you should answer your question and mark it as solved. Dont only seek help when you need, try also to share solutions to help out others.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to automatically signing certificate, i have unchecked that and i have enter the certificate manually